# I've tried to clean this up as much as possible, but it still shows errors

Tags: c#

Alright, so I have just started to code and I have created a button, and now I am coding it. My code keeps giving me these 3 errors, no matter how much I try to troubleshoot. Please help?

```
public class MainButtonClick : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject textBox;
    public int ClickTheButton { get; set; } {
        textBox.SetActive{true};
    }
}
```

The errors:

Error 1:

> Assets/Scripts/MainButtonClick.cs(3,45): error CS9010: Primary constructor body is not allowed

Error 2:

> Assets/Scripts/MainButtonClick.cs(4,25): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `{'

Error 3:

> Assets/Scripts/MainButtonClick.cs(4,31): error CS1002: ; expected

These are probably some very simple coding problems, but it was difficult for me to figure out because not only am I a beginner to c#, I am a beginner to coding as a whole.

Edit 1:

Everything previous was resolved, and my code should be functional, but 2 more errors have occurred..

My code:

```
public class MainButtonClick : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject textBox;
    public int ClickTheButton () {
        textBox.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Error 1:

> Assets/Scripts/MainButtonClick.cs(1,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name MonoBehaviour could not be found. Are you missing UnityEngine using directive?

Error 2:

> Assets/Scripts/MainButtonClick.cs(2,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name GameObject could not be found. Are you missing UnityEngine using directive?

Edit 2:

Ugh.. another problem!!!

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MainButtonClick : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject textBox;
    public int ClickTheButton () {
        textBox.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Error 1:

> Assets/Scripts/MainButtonClick.cs(4,16): error CS0161: MainButtonClick.ClickTheButton(): not all code paths return a value

Comment: when you declare `{ get; set; }` it becomes a property. Think of it  as a variable with some additional features for now. But it looks like you want `ClickTheButton` to be a function. So remove the `{ get ; set } ` and try to compile again .It will look something like this ` public int ClickTheButton () {
        textBox.SetActive{true};
    }`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I will definitely try that out and hopefully it works! Thanks! 

Edit: It got rid of the first error, but the last 2 errors still remain.. any suggestions? @thebenman I may need to replace the "()" with a ";", as the () serves no function.

Comment: You still need '()' after the function name, even when it doesn't contain any parameters.

Comment: The line textBox.SetActive{true}; 
should be textBox.SetActive(true);
Notice change in braces.

Comment: Thanks Poul and Ozair, I will change my code and let you know the outcome! :)

Edit: Whole new problems have occured!! Check Post for edits.

Comment: The compiler does not know, what 'MonoBehaviour' and 'GameObject' is (Where it can find them). You need to add 'Using UnityEngine;' at the top of your .cs file. Basically you should read the errors the compiler gives you.

Comment: ahhhh..... thanks!! As I said, I am a beginner so I have no idea what I'm doing. The help is very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score -1):

**I have finally resolved all problems in my code!**

**Problems:**

1. Deleted unnecessarily added unnecessary stuff.
2. Made brackets around `true` less ***fancy***
3. Made sure that the code knew it was going into Unity so it didn't freak out and ask for a map.
4. Returned a variable back to its caller... it's better when they're together.